# Query on re-apply in Express Entry system

Tags: immigration, canada, resident-permit, ielts, language-test

If an applicant is dropped in end of Jan 2015 Express Entry pool draw due to poor scoring, Can the applicant re-apply with a new express entry profile with better IELTS score in the same year?

Comment: I'm going by what I read on a Canadian immigration lawyer's website. You're in the pool for a year and can modify your application (submit new scores or education info) during it. So you wouldn't re-apply within the same year.

Comment: @mkennedy Are pools formed for every NOC occupation? On What criteria pools are created?

Answer (score 2):

As I read on Express Entry details at CIC official websites, the first draw will be in last week of January 2015. They never said that who are not selected are dropped. They may get chance in subsequent draws. So you should keep working towards improving the score and update the profile when you have some changes in the information which you mentioned today. CIC intends to make such 15 to 25 draws during year 2015.
So January-end is not the end of your hopes.

Please refer this official CIC link for [express entry](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/resources/publications/employers/express-entry-presentation-briefing.asp)